# Get a file through Response without giving it an extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have an ASP.NET page where the user can click a button and get a file that don't have an extension.

```
string fileName = "ExtensionLessFileName";
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.Write("the text content of hte file");
Response.End();
```

The thing is that I need the downloaded file to be extension less but it seems to be impossible since the browser "save as" dialog forces me to make it a txt. I commented the ContentType line and the the file end up as an html.

I would appreciate your help to achieve this or to understand why it is not possible.

Comment: and what is the format you want to save your file to if not text or html?

Comment: What is *wrong* with your OS?

Comment: I need it to be extension less, like "file.name" instead of "file.name.txt"; this is because a SAP program is expecting the file that way. Jim answer worked just fine for me (I'm waiting to mark it as accepted answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the MIME type. I suggest

```
Response.ContentType = "application/unknown";
```

It has worked for me for unknown file types.